# SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data. Spring Data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a procedure for MySQL

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `calculate_user_rank`()
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_rank`;

CREATE TABLE `user_rank`
  AS (SELECT 
user.id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM user_profile WHERE points>x.points) AS rank FROM 
user_profile x, user WHERE user.user_profile_id = x.id);

UPDATE user, user_rank SET user.rank = user_rank.rank WHERE user.id = user_rank.id;

END
```

This stored procedure calculates user rank based on `points` column in `user_profile` table, make a new table `user_rank` with the data and update `user` table `rank` column from the `user_rank` table.

When I execute this Stored Procedure from MySQL Workbench, it works fine. But when I call it from `JpaRepository` as:

```
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "CALL calculate_user_rank()")
void setUserRank();
```

It throws an exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2620)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6995)
```

Is there something wrong with the procedure?

Comment: i am not so experienced with JPA, but the error states that the SP is of type UPDATE, it will not return a result set, as in standard java, you would run it using executeUpdate, not executeQuery() .. may be u need to tell JPA that this SP will not return a resultSet

Comment: @Yazan The `void ` return type informs `JPA` that I do not expect any results.

Comment: not your method, it's when JPA "Engine" executes this qry, how should it be treated, sgould the engine expect a ResultSet, a scalar value, nothing ... that's what i mean, it's in a different layer, a little lower than your method may be ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not annotation `@Query`, it's `@Procedure`:

```
@Transactional
@Procedure(procedureName = "calculate_user_rank")
void setUserRank();
```

Comment: Excellent. I can accept the answer in 4 minutes. LMAO.

Comment: While I understand why `@Procedure` should work, what I don't understand is that why the native query isn't working. Because ultimately it is executed as a raw SQL query. Isn't that right?

Comment: @ShubhamA. U're right, but I `@Query` should return record unless you add `@Modifying` on the method.

Answer (score 3):

Add just @Modifying.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "CALL calculate_user_rank()")
void setUserRank();
```